# Access static properties of a child class without overriding accessors

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, oop, static

Let's say I have a base class and a child class. Consider the following example:

```
class Animal {
  public static type = "any animal";

  public getType() {
    return Animal.type;
  }

  public setType(newType: string) {
    Animal.type = newType;
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  public static type = "dog";
}
```

As you can see, the base class (`Animal` in this example) declares the **static** `type` property, and provides accessors for it (`getType` and `setType`). But the child class (`Dog`) has overriden that static `type` property.
Let's do a `console.log` to see what types we get from an instance of each class:

```
const animal = new Animal();
const dog = new Dog();

console.log(animal.getType()); // any animal
console.log(dog.getType()); // any animal
```

We got the value of base's class property in both cases. That's because of the `Animal.type` expression in the accessor declarations.

#### So, is it possible to use child class for static property referencing without a need to override the accessor methods?

Like in this manner:

```
public getType() {
    return <ChildClass>.type;
}
```

If no, are there any useful workarounds I could use instead of overriding the method each time?

Comment: You could use `this.constructor` instead of `Animal`, but TypeScript won’t understand that… you’d need something like `(this.constructor as typeof Animal)`.  If nobody else gets here before I get to a real computer I will post an answer.

Comment: `setType` should absolutely not be a method of the instances! It affects all instances, not the one you are calling it on. Really there shouldn't be a setter for the type at all.